# Only First row Has Cell Formatting

Tags: php, html, css, sql

This code is used to create a table but I want the dates in the rows to have different colors. The first row colors are there but the second row has nothing.

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word;">
    <tr>
        <th>Visit</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Solution</th>
        <th>Bentley Products</th>
        <th>Est. Value</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Next Step</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
      include "include/connect.php";
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Presales";
      $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)
        or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

      while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) { 
        //This loop is only formatting the first row
        $fromDate = $row['Date_Visit'];
        $newDate = date_format($fromDate,'Y-m-d');
        $toDate = $row['Last_Communicated'];
        $newDate1 = date_format($toDate,'Y-m-d');
        $Week1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
        $Today = date('Y-m-d');

        if ($newDate < $Today) {
            $dcolour = "Green";
        } else {
            $dcolour = "Red";
        }

        echo "<tr>
            <td bgcolor='$dcolour'>$newDate</td>
            <td >$newDate1</td>
            <td>". $row["Company"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Country"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Solution"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Bentley_Products"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Est_Value"]. " (". $row["Currency_ID"]. ")</td>
            <td>". $row["Status"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Next_Step"]. "</td>
            <td>". $row["Comments"]. "</td>
        </tr>";
      }
    ?>

</table>
```

I am not sure why the code is doing this and need help.

Please if someone could help me.

Comment: You should use [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime)'s or [timestamps](http://php.net/time) to do your comparison. Right now you're comparing strings which is probably why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: Casting might help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try :nth-child(1).

Example:

```
table tr:nth-child(1) {
   your style
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: This does not take the date into account.

Comment: Thanks, i found the problem. Was the class="table table-striped". This class was overwriting my styling for the dates.